# How to stay in the queue?

Tags: asterisk

When a device has been added added to the queue after `VMAuthenticate`, how to make sure member to stay in the queue? device get hangup after `Playback`.

I do not wish to use `AgentLogin` because I am not using `agent.conf`.

```
exten => 200,1,Answer()
same => n,Set(MemberChannel=${CHANNEL(channeltype)}/${CHANNEL(peername)})
same => n,Playback(silence/1)
same => n,VMAuthenticate(@default)
same => n,AddQueueMember(campaign-queue,${MemberChannel})
same => n,Playback(agent-loginok)
```

Edit: To clarify, after VMAuthenticate() has been passed, the device should not hang up and it will wait for the call from the Queue. I want something like  `AgentLogin()` without `agent.conf` requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it via

```
 asterisk -rx "queue show"
```

You also can use callback login, which assume you always on and try call back number you specified.

As option you can add Local/agent_id@callback_to_agent/n as channel and build dialplan context callback_to_agent which will find your agent/check it reachable via jabber, skype or special application.

Comment: Does it have to be "Local"? `Set(MemberChannel=${CHANNEL(channeltype)}/${CHANNEL(peername)})` is translated something like `SIP/accountname` and I add it in `AddQueueMember`

Comment: It can be any. Local will just allow control callout by dialplan. So more customization.

Comment: I have tested and it work, however, it is not what I was expecting. I have updated question to clarify what I mean.

Comment: you can't have somethign like agentlogin without login. You can send after auth to conference room, and send to same room caller using Local/ diallling. however you also need check that agent still in room and that you send only ONE client to that room.